# Drawimage(Image, Rectangle) crops original Image

Tags: c#, printing, graphics, drawimage, printdocument

I'm trying to print an Image from a file, but Graphics.DrawImage crops the image when I try to print it.
Example:
When I try to print the [Mona Lisa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr1jr.jpg) the output is [cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y28bp.jpg)

This seemes to be the same problem but the solution doesn't work for me:
[DrawImage scales original image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188689/drawimage-scales-original-image)

My Code:

```
private void print()
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        
        pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
        pd.Print();
    }

    private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Leres75\Desktop\MonaLisa.jpg");
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
        img.Save(@"C:\Users\Leres75\Desktop\TestOutput.jpg"); //not Cropped
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, rect);
    }
```

I tried different variants of the DrawImage method and tried messing aroung with my screen settings to change the DPI but the output doesn't change.

How do I print the whole image?

Comment: Is the image bigger than the page? The "cropped" version you have shown has a very similar H:V ratio to an A4 page, which makes me think you're simply trying to draw the image outside the bounds of the page.

Comment: _tried messing aroung with my screen settings to change the DPI but the output doesn't change._ Doubtful. If you set the _dpi_  (of the image!!) __correctly__ (and you __need__ to do this, no good keeping the random settings the images come with) the result will surely change..

Comment: With the Mona Lisa the Image bounds are: Width = 687, Height= 1024 and the page bounds are Width = 827, Height = 1169

Comment: this is the pdf that gets printed: [link](https://oszimt-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/kessler_pavel_oszimt_onmicrosoft_com/EamoIF6mLhdCuBQEPczyGiYBXiCUvNG_HSL2mvnEOvtfYg?e=PfOqhA)

Comment: _image bounds are: Width = 687, Height= 1024_  -  Do not __ignore__ the image's `dpi` ! `DrawImage` will not ignore it either!!!

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I've got a way around it:
I'm resizing the image so that it fits the page. This works for me since my images are in the A4 format anyway.
I'm using this to resize the image: [How to resize an Image C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/how-to-resize-an-image-c-sharp)

My code is now:

```
private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\pavel\OneDrive - OSZ IMT\Desktop\MonaLisa.jpg");
        Image resizedImage = ResizeImage(img, e.PageSettings.PaperSize.Width, e.PageSettings.PaperSize.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(resizedImage, 0, 0);
    }
```